# Dynamically adding event handler in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've encountered a weird problem with Javascript. What I was given is a string of certain format that I will try to create a table out of.

The table will only have a cell per row and the format of the string is:
Content needs to be displayed for each cell (row)
@
parameter that will be passed to the `onmouseover` event handler which gets called when the user moves their mouse over the displayed text.

The JS code:

```
// the string of format
var stringProof = document.getElementById("stringProof").value;
var arrayOfProof = stringProof.split("#");

// find the table
var table = document.getElementById("proofTable");
// remove what's within
table.innerHTML = "";

for(var i = currentIndex*4;i < end;i++)
{
    // iterative create the text, span, cell and row
    var currentStepProof = arrayOfProof[i];
    var elementsInCurrentStepProof = currentStepProof.split("@");

    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var td = document.createElement("td");

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.onmouseover = function() {alert(elementsInCurrentStepProof[1]);};
    var text = document.createTextNode(elementsInCurrentStepProof[0]);
    span.appendChild(text);
    td.appendChild(span);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

The problem is it does not matter which rows the `onmouseover` function is triggered, it will only alert the parameter of the last row which means the parameter of last row's `onmouseover` function overwrites what was passed to the previous row's `onmouseover` functions.

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot!!~~

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your handler functions share exactly the same "elementsInCurrentStepProof" variable.  Because it changes with every iteration of that `for` loop, all the handlers will "see" it in its final state (that of the last iteration).

You can give each handler its own copy of the value like this:

```
span.onmouseover = function(element) {
  return function() { alert(element); }
}(elementsInCurrentStepProof[1]);
```

By using an intermediary function, you create a new storage scope (a closure) for a copy of the value. Note that it's not enough to make a copy of "elementsInCurrentStepProof", because the value of that variable is a reference to an array. You need to pass the value of element 1.

Comment: I tried you code and now I am getting [object MouseEvent] as the onmouseover function gets called (everyone of them)

Comment: @user1935724 uhh ... are you *sure* you copied that code exactly as in my answer?  The function that gets returned should not have a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/BhLfk/

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.data = elementsInCurrentStepProof[1];
span.onmouseover = function(event) {alert(event.target.data);};
```

Please note your question is missing some information which make it a little bit harder to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user1935724 To answer your question for getting [object MouseEvent], I think you may missed the part "(elementsInCurrentStepProof[1])" at the end of the line in the answer from Pointy, which forces the function to use specific parameter instead of the default mouse event. See my answer for a easier-to-understand solution. It is basically doing the same thing as Pointy's answer.